# PIP Install Consider adding this directory to PATH

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Всем привет!
При установке пакета, выскакивают баги:
Обновляюсь так !pip install --user ИмяПакета

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
  WARNING: The script tqdm.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\sanitarn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location
```

Comment: Это не баги, а предупреждения. Добавьте папку "C:\Users\sanitarn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts" в переменную окружения PATH.

Comment: @insolor данная папка присутствует физически.

Comment: [PATH (переменная)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F))